# RSVP "Yes" or "No" to recurring Google Calendar event based on day of week

Tags: google-calendar

Let's say I'm invited to a recurring meeting on Google Calendar that is scheduled for every Wednesday, and Friday. However, I have a permanent conflict on Fridays, so I can only make Wednesdays.

Is there a way that I can RSVP "Yes" for all of the Wednesday dates going forward, and "No" for all of the Friday dates (without having to respond to them one at a time each week)?

(Note: I don't own the event, so I can't change how it's scheduled).

Comment: RELATED: [Can I accept only certain dates of a recurring event? Or is it all or none?](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/126279410/can-i-accept-only-certain-dates-of-a-recurring-event-or-is-it-all-or-none?hl=en). Hint: "You'd have to accept all events as one, and then go through and individually delete the specific events that you don't want to attend."